# Can't log into SQL server after changing computer name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2, after joining to domain I changed computer name and mistakenly I deleted the administrators group from SQL Server login users and now I am not able to login.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the steps in this article: http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/

Basically you have to modify the SQL Server Service settings so that it starts in admin mode. This will only allow one connection to it. Once you start it up you can create a new sysadmin user that you can use from then on.

Also I do know that you need to run certain scripts on a SQL Server if you change the hostname of the server. You should find them if you google them.

Comment: Thank you for the link but, I think, I need to login to SQL server for running script.

Comment: I read the instruction you provided, it is perfect, I think it will solve my problem I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old but I just used the Gui instead.

Step 1. Start SSMS

Step 2. Select the server name drop down and click browse more.

[image]

step 3. select local or network tab based where the server is and expand Database engine and select the correct `computer name\sql server`
[image]

Comment: For someone that has SQL Server as part of their domain, this might not work. However, in my case, this was a local sql instance used for development, and the above solution actually did work for me.  Apparently when the computer is renamed, I needed to reselect my sql instance under the new computer name in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @user3308241 You can also do this in the Network server tab instead of the local servers tab in the screenshot. Thanks for the input, I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: This answer works for me! After I changed computer name

Answer (score 4):

If you have mixed mode authentication enabled on the SQL Server instance, you can login using the `sa` account, with the password that you specified during installation.

If you have only Windows authentication enabled, I'm not sure. You could *try* running setup again and seeing if it will let you change the authentication mode, but somehow I doubt that it will let you do anything without first connecting to the instance with your Windows identity.

As a last resort, you could try uninstalling and re-installing the SQL Server instance, then re-attaching all your databases.

Comment: SQL server is in windows authentication mode and, I think I have to uninstall and then re install the sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new name of the computer and you should be able to login again..