# WIndowsAuthentication does not work after renaming computer

Tags: sql-server

After renaming the computer, SQL server windows authentication fails, saying `OldPC\user1`  couldn't be authenticated. Rather it should look for `NewPC\user1`. How to resolve the issue ?

I read this [SO quest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495759/cant-log-into-sql-server-after-changing-computer-name) The accepted solution [suggested here](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/), say to stop SQL server instance as below -

[image]

But for me Sql server Configuration displays this error -

[image]

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2008? What service pack?

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is Sql 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that doesn't require restarting the service, starting in single user mode, etc. is to use [PSExec from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) (well, Microsoft now). You can run this to launch SSMS:

```
PsExec -s -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\...\ssms.exe"
--------^ s = "system"
```

You will be prompted to connect. The authentication method will be Windows auth, and the username will be hard-coded to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. Once connected, you will be able to go into security and fix the `sa` password, add yourself as admin, add other admins, etc.

The following article has more details and several caveats you should read before trying this. You may also want to review the comments at the bottom:

- [Recover access to a SQL Server instance](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Of course after you've changed the underlying server name you probably want to restart anyway, after issuing the following:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver N'OldPC';
GO
EXEC sp_addserver N'NewPC', LOCAL;
GO
```

Also, if you've hard-coded the SQL Server service to *start* as a local user, say `OldPC\user1`, and you've renamed the server, you'll also want to fix that in the properties of the service. Right-click in SQL Server Configuration Manager, hit Properties, move to the Log On tab, fix the user name / password, hit Apply, say yes to the prompt about restarting the service, and restart the service.

[image]

But you shouldn't need to use single-user mode, which essentially requires you to restart twice.

---

One way to avoid this problem: leave your machine name as `OldPC`. Or decide on the final name of the server *before* installing SQL Server and everything else...